# Advanced search - pagination

Tags: php, mysql

Can you guys please suggest good advanced search (with multiple criteria fields) pagination.
The problem is how to save data (input by user) to keep the same search criterias when going to page 2, 3 etc.

Comment: Just use the appropriate `LIMIT` clause in MySQL query?

Comment: @Tibor `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should insert your search parameters in GET request. For example:

`search.php?page=N&someparameter=x&otherparameter=y`

These links should be in your pagination.

Answer (score 0):

**Use sessions to store user input data and use session variables to search which will be same in other pages if pagination is available.**